# Heron mc/ Openlayers wms load

Tags: geoserver, geoext, openlayers-2, heron-mapping-client

I have configured a webviewer using Geoserver/Openlayers/Geoext and Heron-mc.

In the examples the overlays and baselayers automaticaly load when first starting the application.

I have changed the setup to meet my needs, but when I load the webpage containing the viewer the wms-layers do not load. Only when I pan, zoom or change layers the request is being made...

Does anyone have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: I'd recommend not using Heron-mc. You are handcuffed to old versions of ExtJS and GeoExt. I use ExtJS 4.2 with GeoExt2 and OpenLayers 2.12.

Comment: How did you modify the code? Can you give an example of the code you have?